# Chart.js : Is there a way to name each bubble in chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I have created a bubble chart using chart.js,which looks like the below[image: Bubble chart]

Is there a way to name each and every bubble in the chart? I am planning to put a data box below this chart. On clicking each bubble data box should display info associated with each bubble. Each bubble will have its own data like maturity_date,bond_type,credit_rating,symbol,etc... How can I name each bubble? These bubbles are created dynamically. This is the code I use to create the chart

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({url: "xxxxxxxx.x.xx", success: function(result){
                var dataObj = {};
                dataObj.datasets = [];
                var object = {};
                object.label = 'First Dataset';
                object.backgroundColor = [];
                object.hoverBackgroundColor = [];
                object.data = [];
                var resultData = result.data;
                var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
                for (var i=0; i<resultData.length; i++) {
                    if(resultData[i].hasOwnProperty("maturity_date") && resultData[i].hasOwnProperty("ask_ytm")) {
                        var maturity_date = resultData[i].maturity_date.split("-");
                        var matYear = new Date(maturity_date[1]+"-"+maturity_date[0]+"-"+maturity_date[2]).getFullYear();
                        if (resultData[i].bond_type == "Tax Free" )
                        {
                        object.backgroundColor.push("#34A10C");
                        object.hoverBackgroundColor.push("#34A10C");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        object.backgroundColor.push("#1130E8");
                        object.hoverBackgroundColor.push("#1130E8");
                        }
                    object.data.push({x: (matYear - currentYear), y: resultData[i].ask_ytm, r: 4});
                    }
                }
                dataObj.datasets.push(object);
                var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
                var myBubbleChart = new Chart(ctx,{
                    type: 'bubble',
                    data : dataObj,
            legend: {
            display: false
                    },
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
                  }
                });

            }});

    });
```

Comment: You don't want to have them as legends?

Comment: No I don't want to have them as legends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data declaration, you can add custom properties if you need to :

```
data: [{
    x: 20,
    y: 30,
    r: 15,
    symbol: "£",
    bond_type: "corporate"
}, {
    x: 40,
    y: 10,
    r: 10,
    symbol: "$",
    bond_type: "james"
} /* ... */]
```

Since this data is dynamic, you need to do it from your back-end of course.

---

Afterwards, you can access these new properties in your callback (*`onClick` event for instance*) :

```
options: {
    onClick: function(e) {
        var element = this.getElementAtEvent(e);

        if (element.length > 0) {

            var data = this.config.data.datasets[element[0]._datasetIndex].data[element[0]._index];

            console.log(data);
            // You can have the following for instance :
            // data -> { x:40, y:10, r:10, symbol:"$", bond_type:"james" }
        }
    }
}
```